# Access phpmyadmin with a password in url

Tags: mysql, passwords, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed the password of my database on mySQL(via phpMyadmin) using a query to update my password. Now I cannot access it, via my browser.

Here is the error message:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Is there a config file I can edit? 
THnaks

Comment: The error implies that no password was passed to PMA. Did you set the password in the application accordingly? http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install

Comment: Nope. The password is set. And so is the config file.

Comment: See "phpMyAdmin: [Using Authentication Modes](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#authentication-modes)".